# Security concerns with compiling latex dynamically on a web server

Tags: php, pdf, latex, pdflatex

I'm setting up a website which would allow users to use certain select latex commands to build a document. They would then be able to preview the document, which means I would:

- parse the text file to make sure only the allowed commands are there
- use PHP to send the user's text to the `pdflatex` command
- display the outputted pdf to the user

How secure is this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have a look at [How can I safely compile other people's LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10418/3335) at our sister site about TeX and LaTeX for the right TeX configurations to use. Parsing a file to make sure only white-listed commands are in there might limit your users too much (or give them some loopholes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's reasonably secure if you don't enable `\write18`. Of course you should use `chroot` and `ulimit` if you are running Unix. See [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-60001.4) for the security of [TeXLive 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/). And see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10418/5763) for the answer on TeX.SX.